# How to achieve VPN connection over Hughesnet?

Tags: networking, vpn, satellite

I'm using Cisco AnyConnect to connect to my company's VPN and I succesfully can connect using any network with the exception of Hughesnet, the one I use when I'm in the country.

I contacted the local support and these guys don't know what to do in order to make it works. Sometimes I acheved make the connection using Hughesnet, but this is less than 5% of the times. So, I know the connection is not completely impossible. My guess is that sometimes the latency is good enough to make the connection.

How can I reduce the latency in this type of network? Or what else can I do to achieve a VPN connection using Hughesnet?

Comment: High latency shouldn’t cause an inability to connect to a VPN.  You would just be increasing an already high latency.  One does not decrease traditional GEO satellite internet.  You have to determine if your inability is due to a DNS server problem or something else.

Comment: Not sure why are you talking about DNS. I'm using the IP of the server. This is the log message:
22:23:49 Contacting X.X.241.70. 
22:23:56 Connection attempt has failed.
22:23:56 Unable to contact X.X.241.70.

Comment: DNS provides the route for two devices to talk to one another.  Your error log indicates the client device cannot contact the server

Comment: I can ping the server using the IP but the latency is high: 750 ms on average.

Comment: I have to ask;  you are absolutely sure you have a SSH server on the other end?  Have you tried using a proxy in the event your ISP is blocking common ports used by protocols like SSH

Comment: No, I'm not sure about your question. The IP is the provided to establish the VPN connection and sometimes I can achieve it, so I don't think they are blocking the port.

Comment: Sorry; When I said SSH I meant a VPN service